# Amazon ec2 set up best practices for Rails app with mysql or postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have to setup ec2 for a medium rails app running on apache2, mysql, capistrano and a few background services. I would like to know what is the best practices that every developer usually does to set up his rails app. I would like to know what kind of setup that is easy to scale and can mimimic at least

- auto deployment
- security
- regular data backup and an easy and quick way to restore the data
- server recovery
- fault tolerance

I am also interested in how to monitor the server status and performance and other kind of best practice would be also helpful.

ps: take into account also that my app database will grow a fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a good look into the AWS docs and in particular the [architecture center](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/) would be the best place to start. However, let me address as many of your questions as I can.

**Database**

The easiest way to get a scalable, fault tolerant database on AWS is to use the [Relational Database Service](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/). You should read the docs and best practices to ensure you get the most out of it - ie. multiple AZs.

**EC2 Servers**

The most recommended way to structure your servers is to decouple them into Web Servers (serve html to users) and App Servers (application logic, usually returns json or xml etc). See [this](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_web_01.pdf) architecture example. 

However, the key is to use an [AutoScaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) group behind an [Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/).

**Automation**

If you want to use capistrano, just install it into your servers. You could create a pre-configured [AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) with it installed along with whatever else you want. Alternatively, you could install it in a deployment script. However, the most recommended method for this kind of thing is to use the AWS [OpsWorks](https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/) service which is Chef in the cloud.

**Server Recovery & Fault Tolerance**

If you use EC2 AutoScaling, if a server becomes unavailable ie. hardware fails or it stops replying to EC2 health checks, AutoScaling will automatically terminate it and launch a replacement.

With the addition of the ELB and ELB health checks, instances that stop responding to web requests can be brought out of service by the ELB.

You need to read the docs for more info on this.

**Backup and Recovery**

For backing up data on EBS volumes attached to EC2 instances, use [EBS Snapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html). However, the best types of architectures keep EC2 instances stateless - they don't store anything except application code, if they died it wouldn't matter. In these situations all data, including user files can be stored on [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/). On S3, you have a number of back up options such as [Cross Region Replication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) and or data archiving to [Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/details/)

**Monitoring**

AWS provides [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) which can provide you with hypervisor visible metrics such as network in and out, CPU utilization and more. If you want to get more data, you could use [custom metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/publishingMetrics.html) and push things like eg. memory usage. In addition to cloudwatch, you could use a server level monitoring tool.

**Deployment**

I recommend [AWS Code Deploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html).

**Security**

Use [Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) to open only the ports you want users to be able to connect on. Also, use security groups to lock down important ports eg.22 to only a specific set of IPs. You can also use [Network ACLS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) to block undesired traffic. AWS provides more information and suggestions [here](https://aws.amazon.com/security/).

I also recommend you read [this](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/designing-fault-tolerant-applications/) Whitepaper.